# Why explicit conversion required to assign base class to derived class? But not required to do the reverse

Tags: c#, types, variable-assignment, radix, derived

I have a base class and a derived class as bellow

```
public class animal
{
    public string name { get; set; }
}

public class dog : animal
{
    public int age { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
}
```

### uses:

```
animal a = new animal();

dog d = new dog();

a = d; //compiled

d = a; //Error:Cannot implicitly convert type 'animal' to 'dog'.

d = (dog)a; // compiled
```

What happen internally that derived class can assigned to base but doing the reverse explicit conversion is required? Same result found even both base and derived class contains same member.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you use explicit conversion, in your case, you are telling the compiler that you know what is going on.  If you were to compile your code, removing `d = a;`, and you tried to access a public member on `d`, and exception would be thrown.  That is because, in this instance, the `animal` is not a `dog`.  You explicitly created an `animal` and assigned it to `a`.

Explicit conversion allows you to do thing when you *know* the conversion will work.

```
public class MyClass
{
    public animal MyAnimal { get; private set; }

    public MyClass ()
    {
        MyAnimal = new dog ();
    }

    public void SetAge (int Age)
    {
        ((dog)MyAnimal).age = Age;
    }
}
```

In this case, we know that `MyAnimal` is actually a `dog`, so we can do an explicit cast to it.  All of this works because of inheritance.  Because inheritance does not work both ways, the complier will not allow an implicit up cast--you must do it explicitly.

We know that when a class inherits from its base class, it takes with it the public properties and methods.  You cannot say that your reference to an `animal` will always contain the properties and methods of a `dog`.

Answer (score 10):

All dogs are animals, but not all animals are dogs. Implicit conversion is not allowed because your a might not actually be a d.

Comment: thanks Marty..actually i am looking for some internal explanation...what happen in memory allocation..why CLR cannt allow implicit conversion...and all the internal working in respect to CLR,memory management...

Answer (score 4):

Its a simple rule of inheritance cast. For example: *Dog is Animal* but reverse is not true - `Animal is Dog`. There may be number of sub-classes of Animal.

```
class Animal {}
class Dog : Animal {}
class Cat : Animal {}

Animal a=new Cat(); // OK
a=new Dog(); // OK

Cat c=a; //Invalid - var a might contains reference of Cat or Dog
Cat d=(Cat)a; // Throws InvalidCastException exception because "a" has ref. of Dog
```

So, super class reference variable can hold reference of sub-class object without cast but when you assign reference from the super class reference variable to the sub-class reference variable you must have to cast.

Have a look at MSDN article - [How to: Safely Cast by Using as and is Operators (C# Programming Guide).](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc488006.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

Think of it this way, all dogs are already animals but not all animals are dogs. To assign an animal to a dog you must first convert it to a dog.

Comment: Lets convert all animals to dogs :D

Comment: A Simpler yet clear explanation

Answer (score 2):

> What happen internally that derived class can assigned to base but doing the reverse explicit conversion is required? Same result found even both base and derived class contains same member.

Almost nothing is happening internally, in either case. The object is not being modified, or copied; rather, it's simply that a reference to it is being stored in a new variable with a different type.

The implicit conversion from `dog` to `animal` is allowed because if a `dog` variable can hold a reference to an object, then the object must be a `dog` or a `poodle` or whatnot, so an `animal` variable can also hold a reference to it.

By contrast, an explicit conversion is required from `animal` to `dog` because the `animal` object really might not be a `dog`, in which case the run-time system will raise an exception. (Remember when I said that "almost nothing is happening internally"? It's "*almost* nothing" because the run-time system will have to check to ensure that the object is a `dog`, and to raise an exception otherwise.)

This is a language design decision — we could definitely create a language that's exactly like C#, except that `dog d = a;` is equivalent to `dog d = (dog) a;`, but the designers of C# (and many similar languages) felt that it would be confusing for `dog d = a;` to raise a run-time exception sometimes. The explicit cast makes clear that an exception is possible unless `a` refers to a `dog`.